# jquery-autocomplete-multiple-output

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

hello i had populated textbox on basis of search criteria ie if i type a then items starting with a is populated in textbox and also i have used another textbox in which i displayed partyname but the issue is that when i select the value in item  textbox it is not displaying in textbox but partyname textbox is working ie when i select partyname from dropdown it is displaying in hidden field and textbox but in case of item it is not working i m sending my jquery function so please help

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    SearchText();
    SearchItem();
});

function SearchText() {
    $('input[name$="tbAuto"]').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "PartyList.asmx/FetchPartyList",
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('input[name$="tbAuto"]').val(ui.item.Name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('input[name$="tbAuto"]').val(ui.item.Name);
            $('input[name$="tbHidden"]').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a>' + item.Name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
    };
}


function SearchItem() {
    $('input[name$="txtitem"]').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Itemslist.asmx/FetchItemList",
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('input[name$="txtitem"]').val(ui.item1.Name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('input[name$="txtitem"]').val(ui.item1.Name);
            $('input[name$="hditem"]').val(ui.item1.value);
            return false;
        }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item1) {
        return $('<li>').data('item1.autocomplete', item1).append('<a>' + item1.Name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

ItemInfo class:

```
public class Iteminfo
{
    connection oConnection = new connection();
    Control oControl = new Control();
    AccountInfo oAccount = new AccountInfo();
    connection c = new connection();

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }

    public List<Iteminfo> GetItems(string prefixText)
    {
        List<Iteminfo> itemList = new List<Iteminfo>();

        try
        {
            DataTable dt;
            AccountInfo oAccount = new AccountInfo();
            //dt = oAccount.GetAccountInfo((int)HttpContext.Current.Session["CompCode"], 0);
            dt = oAccount.GetIteminfo(prefixText);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    itemList.Add(new Iteminfo() { Name = dt.Rows[i]["groupname"].ToString() + dt.Rows[i]["subgroup"].ToString() + dt.Rows[i]["itemname"], Title = dt.Rows[i]["itemname"].ToString(), 
                    value = dt.Rows[i]["groupname"].ToString() + dt.Rows[i]["subgroup"].ToString() + dt.Rows[i]["itemname"].ToString()+";"+dt.Rows[i]["itemcode"].ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            itemList.Add(new Iteminfo() { Name = "Problem Getting Results.", value = "Error" });
        }

        if (itemList.Count == 0)
            itemList.Add(new Iteminfo() { Name = "Nothing to Display.", value = "Info" });

        return itemList;
    }
}
```

Page method:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Iteminfo> FetchItemList(string prefix)
{
    var items = new Iteminfo();
    var fetchitems = items.GetItems(prefix);
    //.Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(prefix.ToLower()));

    // .Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(prefix.ToLower()));
    return fetchitems.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML/ASPX code as well and make your issue description a little bit more clear?

Comment: why the select event is not generating of second textbox ui element

Comment: So did the answer helped you, do you still have the issues?

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue seems to be in `SearchItem` function. You should not be changing all those `item` to `item1` as this is internal jQuery UI name and it is always the same (for all instances). So your JavaScript function should look like this:

```
function SearchItem() {
    $('input[name$="txtitem"]').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Itemslist.asmx/FetchItemList",
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "' }",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('input[name$="txtitem"]').val(ui.item.Name);
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('input[name$="txtitem"]').val(ui.item.Name);
            $('input[name$="hditem"]').val(ui.item.value);
            return false;
        }
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li>').data('item.autocomplete', item).append('<a>' + item.Name + '</a>').appendTo(ul);
    };
}
```

There might be some further errors regarding selectors but this is impossible to tell without the HTML/ASPX code.